# Calling hsql function from java

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am trying to call oracle function from java using hsqldb for integration test.

Function: (function.sql)

```
FUNCTION balance (acct_id NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
acct_bal NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT bal INTO acct_bal FROM accts WHERE acct_no = acct_id;
  RETURN acct_bal;
END;
```

Java Code:

```
    int acctNo = 0;
    CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{? = CALL balance(?)}");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.FLOAT);
    cstmt.setInt(2, acctNo);
    cstmt.executeUpdate();
    float acctBal = cstmt.getFloat(1);
    System.out.print("Test print: " + acctNo +  " " +acctBal);
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BALANCE
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me in this regard.
Note: Creating table and inserting data is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You must then change the function into HSQLDB syntax and create it after the tables. The modified function will look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION balance (acct_id INTEGER) RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE acct_bal DOUBLE;
  SELECT bal INTO acct_bal FROM accts WHERE acct_no = acct_id;
  RETURN acct_bal;
END;
```